# react-native-maps kind of used Google-Map

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I don't have a delevoper problem per se, my question is more related to an administrativ perspective.

Which kind of map is used by react-native-maps ?

- Mobile Native Static Maps
- Mobile Native Dynamic Maps
- Embed
- Embed Advanced
- Static Maps
- Dynamic Maps
- Static Street View
- Dynamic Street View

Reason is the new regulation at 2018-June-11 and the kind of pricing.
I need to calculate the upcoming costs.

Sources: 
Google-Maps-Platform: 
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/

Price-List: 
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

thanking you in anticipation

Chris

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: the question isn't depend on code

Comment: @Chris-90, did you manage to find an answer for this? i saw that react-native-maps implements the Maps SDK for iOS and it falls under the Dynamic Maps category. is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use many as i've implemented react-native-maps in 1 of my project, the specified types as per the module is
The map type to be displayed.

- standard: standard road map (default)
- none: no map
- satellite: satellite view
- hybrid: satellite view with roads and points of interest overlayed
- terrain: (Android only) topographic view
- mutedStandard: more subtle, makes markers/lines pop more (iOS 11.0+ only)

you can find the complete list of props for styling and using maps here
[React Native Maps ReadMe](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)